# How do I align my navbar so it's permanently in the middle of my white box (without padding etc)?

Tags: html, css

This is my website. The nav bar is causing me horrendous problems. Last night my friend told me it was dropping down and I just don't know how to fix it:

http://i60.tinypic.com/23iigpi.png

So I removed the width and reduced the text on some buttons which is depressing for me.

Anyway, now I want my smaller nav bar to centre in the middle of my white block. Does anyone know the best way?

http://www.simplypsychics.com/null/index-test.html

I have tried:

and modifying various positioning in the CSS but nothing seems to work.

This is my CSS for the nav:

```
#nav {
position: absolute;
top: 98px;
left:15px;
float: left;
list-style: none;
background-image:url(../images/menubanner.png);
background-color: #f5c3fd;
border-radius:7px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
-moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
box-shadow: 1px 3px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}
#nav li {
float: left;
}
#nav li a {
display: block;
padding: 8px 13px;
text-decoration: none;
font-weight: bold;
color: #494949;
border-right: 1px solid #fceaff;
}
#nav li a:hover {
color: #822e8e;
}
#nav .home-icon1 {
background: url(../images/icon-home.png) no-repeat center;
width: 39px;
height: 34px;
background-color: #494949;
color: #f5c3fd;
border-top-left-radius: 7px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 7px;
position: relative;
border-right: 1px solid #fceaff;
float: left;
padding: 0;
list-style: none;
}
#nav .home-icon1 a:hover {
background: url(../images/icon-home.png) no-repeat center;
width: 39px;
height: 34px;
background-color: #494949;
color: #f5c3fd;
border-top-left-radius: 7px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 7px;
position: relative;
border-right: 1px solid #fceaff;
float: left;
padding: 0;
list-style: none;
}
#nav .home-icon2 {
background: url(../images/icon-findapsychic.png) no-repeat left;
padding: 0px 0px 0px 15px;
}
#nav .home-icon3 {
background: url(../images/icon-psychicreadings.png) no-repeat left;
padding: 0px 0px 0px 25px;
}
#nav .home-icon4 {
background: url(../images/icon-bookareading.png) no-repeat left;
padding: 0px 0px 0px 22px;
}
#nav .home-icon5 {
background: url(../images/icon-aboutus.png) no-repeat left;
padding: 0px 0px 0px 30px;
}
#nav .home-icon6 {
background: url(../images/icon-help.png) no-repeat left;
padding: 0px 0px 0px 14px;
}
```

and this is my HTML:

```
<div id="nav" style="margin:0 auto !important;">
<li class="home-icon1" onclick="window.location.href='http://www.simplypsychics.com/'"></li>
<li class="home-icon2"><a href="http://www.simplypsychics.com/readers/" target="_parent">FIND A PSYCHIC READER</a></li>
<li class="home-icon3"><a href="http://www.simplypsychics.com/readings/" target="_parent">PSYCHIC READINGS</a></li>
<li class="home-icon4"><a href="http://www.simplypsychics.com/book/" target="_parent">BOOK A READING</a></li>
<li class="home-icon5"><a href="http://www.simplypsychics.com/psychicreadings/" target="_parent">FIND OUT MORE</a></li>
<li class="home-icon6"><a href="http://www.simplypsychics.com/help/" target="_parent">HELP/FAQ</a></li>
</div>
```

Also if the nav bar looks awful for you like it did my friend please let me know! :(

Comment: heard of indentation? It makes the code more legible. Try it, it's cool ^^

Comment: try to give min-width and max-width to your nav, it is overflowing the space, that's why is going down

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On parent (#headerwhiteback) set:
    text-align: center;

Then on #nav, remove:
    position: absolute;
    float: left;

And add this CSS:

```
#nav {
    display: inline-block;

}
#nav::before {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
}
```

Also, to your liking: add margin-top: on #nav (25px seems ok) and make padding-top: on next element, #headertextbottom, much smaller (20px seems ok).

This is just a quick fix for your header. Please remember: CSS looks horrific here and looks set to be rewritten from scratch or only cause you more and more trouble. Good luck!

Comment: To praise my answer: it centers the menu no matter what size is it. Also, please add <ul> tags. Either I'm missing something or lack of them is a childs mistake

Comment: <div id="nav" style="margin:0 auto !important;"> <- change to -> <div id="nav">...remove "margin-bottom: 50px;" and add "margin-top: 25px;" in your css

Comment: So this is the new CSS for Nav? #nav {
    list-style: none;
    background-image:url(../images/menubanner.png);
    background-color: #f5c3fd;
    border-radius:7px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
    box-shadow: 1px 3px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
    display: inline-block;
 margin-top: 25px;
}

Comment: Sorry blonde moment! I forgot it was in the actual code. xD Let me remove from the html file!!! < no joy :(

Answer (score 0):

If the nav bar is more-or-less a set width (`#nav` looks to stay at 840px) then you can set `left:50%` and `margin-left:-420px` (-420 px because it's half the width of the navbar, and we want to move it towards the left). This should work because you've already set the navbar to be positioned absolutely.

You'll have to remove this from the `#nav` div though: `style="margin:0 auto !important;"`

Inline style and `!important` is doubly bad!

Comment: Oh, you'll have to kill the `float: left` as well.